# C++ template class and template function

Tags: c++

If I have one template class and template function like this

```
template <class T> T getMax (T a, T b) {
  return (a>b?a:b);
}

template <class T> class GetMax {
public:
    static T getMax(T a, T b) {
        return (a>b?a:b);   
    }       
};
```

Why are these not valid?

```
x=getMax(1, '2');
```

but these are valid

```
x=getMax(1,2);
```

Does it mean that there is no type conversion in template function?

This is not valid

```
x=GetMax::getMax(1, 2);
```

Does it mean that for the template class, the type must be specified?

Comment: The standard itself has a problem similar to your second. `std::pair<T1, T2>` must have its type specified. That's why there is a `std::make_pair<T1,T2>(T1, T2)` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What should `getMax(1, '2');`  return? An int, or a char? Think about it :)

You could write:

```
template <class T1, class T2> T1 getMax (T1 a, T2 b) {
  return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

But note that you are explicitly returning type 1, what might not work in a case like `getMax('1',1000)` because 100 would be converted to char type, and that wouldn't be large enough.

The latter is not valid because to use a class, you must first state what type it is -- this mechanism acts first, before type deduction.

It would work if you stated it :

```
class GetMax {
public:
    template <class T> 
    static T getMax(T a, T b) {
        return (a>b?a:b);   
    }       
};
```

Comment: I mean why '2' can not be converted to int implicitly?

Comment: @skydoor, how should the compiler know if you want to return a `char` or a `int`?

Comment: @skydoor, the same question could be asked, why can't `1` be converted to char implicitly?

Comment: @skydoor: Because '2' is not an integer. It is a textual representation of one, yes, but so is "two", "TWO" or "II". Should all those be converted implicitly to the integer 2 as well? And if so, how about "deux", "to" or "zwei"? All of those are textual representations of the integer 2.

Answer (score 2):

1) There is type conversion, but it doesn't work together with type inference. Meaning when you specify the type (like `getMax<int>(1,'2')` or `getMax<char>(1,'2')`) it works, but if you don't, the compiler can't infer whether you want `getMax<int>` or `getMax<char>`.

2) Yes, template arguments are inferred only for function templates, not class templates.